# How to write a string that starts with @ and contains " " in C#

Tags: c#

When I change the following C# string

```
string xml="xmlns:qtpRep=\"http://www.mercury.com/qtp/ObjectRepository\""
```

into

```
string xml=@"xmlns:qtpRep=\"http://www.mercury.com/qtp/ObjectRepository\""
```

I get compiler error: ;expected
How can I express the literal double quotes inside a string starting with @ ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You double the double quotes instead of using a backslash:

```
string xml = @"xmlns:qtpRep=""http://www.mercury.com/qtp/ObjectRepository""";
```

(See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) for more details.)

Although in this case it's not clear why you want a verbatim string literal anyway... and for XML attributes it's generally simpler just to use single quotes:

```
string xml = @"xmlns:qtpRep='http://www.mercury.com/qtp/ObjectRepository'";
```

I'm also bound to say that if you're creating XML strings yourself, you're probably Doing It Wrong<sup>TM</sup>. Use an XML API instead :)

Comment: @Inuyasha: That's nothing, one comment of mine got upvoted 10 times in 40 seconds.

Comment: @JonSkeet love the "TM" on Doing It Wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Two double quotes translate to a single quote when the string is verbatim (with `@`).

For example:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"this is ""enclosed in double quotes""");
```

...will write:

> this is "enclosed in double quotes"

Answer (score 0):

Double them up:

```
 string xml = @"xmlns:qtpRep=\""http://www.mercury.com/qtp/ObjectRepository\""";
```